# MongoDB, update an existing collection via aggregate

Tags: arrays, mongodb, concatenation, aggregate, insert-update

I have following mongodb collection

```
    {
    "_id" : "B0006ZPB0S",
    "title" : "Pretty Diamond-cut Black Hills Gold & Sterling Silver Rose Bud Women's Ring",
    "reviews" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "A1GTVGS786CHAN",
            "profileName" : "TheWifey",
            "helpfulness" : "2/2",
            "score" : 5,
            "time" : ISODate("2012-02-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "summary" : "Beautiful!!!",
            "text" : "After 5 years of missing this beautiful ring!! Our oldest daughter accidently flushed my orginal down the drain! It beautiful, doesnt sit too high, and fits great! I love it! Thanks to Amazon.com for such an awesome site! It was a great Valentines gift!"
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "A3H9YQFM3LWVPL",
            "profileName" : "Angela K. Lewis \"Angie\"",
            "helpfulness" : "2/2",
            "score" : 5,
            "time" : ISODate("2011-01-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "summary" : "Pretty, Elegant Ring",
            "text" : "This ring is everything I expected it to be. It is very pretty, goes with any outfit, stays clean and is easy to take care of. I would recommend this ring to anyone who likes silver and Black Hills gold."
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update this collection with this object

```
{
    avgReviewScore:  1.5
    reviewsCount:    200
    reviewScoreDistrib: {
        1: 10
        2: 0
        3: 3
        4: 5
        5: 0
    }
}
```

Number are only for ilustration, numbers are calculated based on above reviews array, only 5 scores are possible (1.0, 2.0 , 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)

```
avgReviewScore:  average of scores in reviews object
reviewsCount:    count number of reviews
reviewScoreDistrib: {
    1:  count number of score 1.0 inside reviews object, if score doesnt exist write 0
    2:  count number of score 2.0 -----
    3:  count number of score 3.0 ----
    4:  count number of score 4.0 ---
    5:  count number of score 5.0 -----
```

I have managed to write this:

```
db.products.aggregate(
    {$match:{}},
       {$addFields : { reviewStats:{
        
           avgReviewScore: {$avg:"$reviews.score"},
           reviewsCount: {$size: "$reviews.score"},
           reviewScoreDistrib: [  ]
               
               
          
          
            }}}     
 )
```

which returns

```
{
    "_id" : "B0006ZPB0S",
    "title" : "Pretty Diamond-cut Black Hills Gold & Sterling Silver Rose Bud Women's Ring",
    "reviews" : [ 
        {
            "userId" : "A1GTVGS786CHAN",
            "profileName" : "TheWifey",
            "helpfulness" : "2/2",
            "score" : 5,
            "time" : ISODate("2012-02-17T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "summary" : "Beautiful!!!",
            "text" : "After 5 years of missing this beautiful ring!! Our oldest daughter accidently flushed my orginal down the drain! It beautiful, doesnt sit too high, and fits great! I love it! Thanks to Amazon.com for such an awesome site! It was a great Valentines gift!"
        }, 
        {
            "userId" : "A3H9YQFM3LWVPL",
            "profileName" : "Angela K. Lewis \"Angie\"",
            "helpfulness" : "2/2",
            "score" : 5,
            "time" : ISODate("2011-01-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "summary" : "Pretty, Elegant Ring",
            "text" : "This ring is everything I expected it to be. It is very pretty, goes with any outfit, stays clean and is easy to take care of. I would recommend this ring to anyone who likes silver and Black Hills gold."
        }
    ],
    "reviewStats" : {
        "avgReviewScore" : 5.0,
        "reviewsCount" : 2,
        "reviewScoreDistrib" : [ 
            1.0, 
            2.0, 
            3.0, 
            4.0, 
            5.0
        ]
    }
}
```

I am not able to get  "reviewScoreDistrib"  right
Something like this

```
"reviewScoreDistrib" :[concat 1 (as number) + ":" + count($review.score" where reviews.score = 1), etc for other scores ]
```

How can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide how the result should look like?

Comment: Not fully clear what you like to get, but have a look at [$bucket](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/bucket/) or $bucketAuto

Comment: I want to update every record on existing collections with reviewStats object which should be calculated based on data in .reviews object . (see above how each record should look like).

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the simplest way to get there.  There's not an immediately clear reason to try create a subdoc `reviewScore.1` vs. just flattening it into the main doc `reviewScore_1`.  This setup also makes it very easy to filter by anything or nothing before getting averages and distributions.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$reviews"}
    ,{$group: {_id:"$_id",
               avgReviewScore: {$avg: "$reviews.score"},
               reviewsCount: {$sum:1},
               reviewScore_1: {$sum: {$cond: {if:{$eq:[1,"$reviews.score"]},then:1,else:0}}},
               reviewScore_2: {$sum: {$cond: {if:{$eq:[2,"$reviews.score"]},then:1,else:0}}},
               reviewScore_3: {$sum: {$cond: {if:{$eq:[3,"$reviews.score"]},then:1,else:0}}},
               reviewScore_4: {$sum: {$cond: {if:{$eq:[4,"$reviews.score"]},then:1,else:0}}},
               reviewScore_5: {$sum: {$cond: {if:{$eq:[5,"$reviews.score"]},then:1,else:0}}}
              }}
]);
```

If you want to get the complete average and distribution, change to this:

```
    ,{$group: {_id:null, ...
```

If you want to get fancy about it, you could use `$reduce` as a way to walk the `reviews` array and selectively increment `1`,`2`, etc. in a subdoc.  It looks a little odd but remember with reduce, you cannot update pieces of the aggregated `$$value` object; you have to reconstruct the *whole* `{1:n,2:n,...}` each time.  This means carrying over the previous value e.g. `$$value.1` and then adding either 1 or 0.  Notice how the value of `$$this` and `$$this.score` are not directly part of the `$reduce` output.  This also satisfies the original request to put `1`,`2`, etc. as fields in a subdoc.  And: **no $unwind**.  This could be a performance boost.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$project: { reviewStats:{
        avgReviewScore: {$avg:"$reviews.score"},
        reviewsCount: {$size: "$reviews.score"}
        ,reviewScoreDistrib: {$reduce: {
            input: "$reviews",
            initialValue: {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0},
                in: {
                    "1":{$add:["$$value.1",{$cond:{if:{$eq:[1,"$$this.score"]},then:1,else:0}}]},
                    "2":{$add:["$$value.2",{$cond:{if:{$eq:[2,"$$this.score"]},then:1,else:0}}]},
                    "3":{$add:["$$value.3",{$cond:{if:{$eq:[3,"$$this.score"]},then:1,else:0}}]},
                    "4":{$add:["$$value.4",{$cond:{if:{$eq:[4,"$$this.score"]},then:1,else:0}}]},
                    "5":{$add:["$$value.5",{$cond:{if:{$eq:[5,"$$this.score"]},then:1,else:0}}]}
                }
        }}
    }
               }}

]);
```

Any conditional logic can appear in the setup.  Here is example of the text length distribution including those cases where it does not exist.  We make use of `$let` here to avoid repeating the `$strLenBytes` expression over and over.  Also, since we are only either adding 0 or 1, we can compactify the logic by simply calling `$toInt` on the resulting boolean.

```
,reviewCommentDistrib: {$reduce: {
    input: "$reviews",
    initialValue: {"long":0,"short":0,"none":0},
    in: {
      $let: {
        vars: {slen: {$strLenBytes: {$ifNull:["$$this.text",""]}} },
        in: {
          "none":{$add:["$$value.none",{$toInt:{$eq:["$$slen",0]}}]},
          "short":{$add:["$$value.short",{$toInt:{
                      $and:[ {$lt:["$$slen",20]},{$gt:["$$slen",0]} ]
          }}]},
         "long":{$add:["$$value.long",{$toInt:{$gte:["$$slen",20]}}]}
         }
       }
     }
}}
```

Comment: The second code with `initialValue: {"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0},
                in: {
                    "1":{$add:["$$value.1",{$cond:{if:{$eq:[1,"$$this.score"]},then:1,else:0}}]}` looks good, but it generates reviewScoreDistrib without colon after 1,2,3,4 and 5, how can I add colon in  reviewScoreDistrib. I want this format   1: 2: 3: 4: 5:   (see my initial post how reviewsScoreDistrib should like.

Comment: I find solution for my previous comment, should look like this `initialValue: {"1:":0,"2:":0,"3:":0,"4:":0,"5:":0},
            in: {
                    "1:":{$add:["$$value.1:",{$cond:{if:{$eq:[1,"$$this.score"]},then:1,else:0}}]},`

Comment: @Bubi  I strongly recommend you do not mix data with formatting, which is what I suspect the colon is for.   Your code should be doing e.g. `printf("%s: %s", key, val)` not `print("%s%s",key,val)`.   That said, don't be shy about hitting the accepted answer checkmark.  ;-)